# Why is Activity statuses Scheduled and Completed added?

Tags: activities, search, issues

Is it a bug that in *Advanced Search* section *Activities* the **Activity Statuses** get filled automatically with **Completed** and **Scheduled**.

It happens when:

1. I open Activities section when doing **Advanced Search**;
2. I try edit Activities section of previously configured **Smart group**.

In (2) scenario, the previously set Activity Statuses are lost and replaced by these Completed and Scheduled, thus annoyingly disrupting the group settings which need to be manually redone.

The bug is present in CiviCRM Drupal sandbox v4.7.15.

Is there a bug report filled for this already?

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: So are you saying that your Saved Search does not included Completed + Scheduled but when you go back to 'edit criteria' they are being added automatically and hence if you were simply trying to edit another aspect of the Saved Search then this could get added unintentionally? If so, yes I would say it is a bug. I can't answer if a bug report already exists but didn't spot it via https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19624?jql=text%20~%20%22saved%20search%22%20ORDER%20BY%20created%20DESC

Comment: wondering if there is more going on with broken 'Saved Searches' since I also spotted that 'edit criteria' for one of mine was resulting in the wrong tag (tag id = 1) showing on the screen rather than the one recorded in the db. also saw this https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19624

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug and has been reported [here](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19706)

Note, it closely resembles other issues affecting 'Edit Smart Criteria' eg

- [Tags](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19705) (affects only 4.6.x but not 4.7.x) and
- [Privacy Radio Buttons](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19624) (affects 4.6.x and 4.7.x)